# Highlighting selected div with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know how to use jquery or JavaScript to apply a onclick event that highlights the selected div and highlights the others..

I have a dynamic row of names the user can click to view selected messages, When the user clicks the selected name the name will be highlighted with a border... Is there a simple way to achieve this sort of event without having to go through the following.

```js
function swapme(foo) {
  buttons = new Array();
  buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  for (i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    if (buttons[i].className === 'active') buttons[i].className = 'inactive';
  }
  document.getElementById('button' + foo).className = 'active';
}
```

```css
.inactive {
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px
}

.active {
  background: #0F0;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  color: #F00;
  padding: 12px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    <a href="#" onclick="swapme('1'); return false;" class="inactive" id="button1">1</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="swapme('2'); return false;" class="inactive" id="button2">2</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="swapme('3'); return false;" class="inactive" id="button3">3</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="swapme('4'); return false;" class="inactive" id="button4">4</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="swapme('5'); return false;" class="inactive" id="button5">5</a>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```

If there is a simple work around please advise, as in maybe a toggle event or a on change.

also possibly without having to go through an array loop..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
let links = document.querySelectorAll('a');
   for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', activateClass);
   }
function activateClass(e) {
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].classList.remove('active');
   }
    e.target.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
.active { background:#0F0 ; border:1px solid #F00 ; color:#F00 ; padding:12px }
```

```html
<p>
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
</p>
```

Comment: i will check this out, thnk u v much

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the loop by using[`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).

You can implement something like the following:

- when clicking on one of the names
- get the current active
- remove the active class from the current active
- add active class to the clicked element

This way you don't need to iterate over all buttons.

Note that you can use `addEventHandler` to add all handlers at once instead of an `onclick` in the html. This should make the code less coupled and easier to maintain.

```js
function swapme(event) {
  // Get current active element(s) 
  document.querySelectorAll('.active')
    // Remove active class
    .forEach(e => e.className = 'inactive');
  // And add the active class to the event target.
  event.target.className = 'active';
  // Prevent default link hanlding
  event.preventDefault();
}

document.querySelectorAll('#container > a')
  .forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', swapme));
```

```css
.inactive {
  background: #666;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 12px
}

.active {
  background: #0F0;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
  color: #F00;
  padding: 12px
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <p id="container">
    <a href="#" class="inactive" id="button1">1</a>
    <a href="#" class="inactive" id="button2">2</a>
    <a href="#" class="inactive" id="button3">3</a>
    <a href="#" class="inactive" id="button4">4</a>
    <a href="#" class="inactive" id="button5">5</a>
  </p>

</body>

</html>
```